# Will SSL protocol ask for handshake after initial handshake?

Tags: ssl, handshake

Will SSL protocol ask for handshake after intial handshake ?

I mean once handshake is done and data transfer is happening. Is there any case in which handshake/authentication needs to be done ? If so, in which case ?

Answer (score 2):

Yes. Either of the peers can request a new handshake at any time: to strengthen the cipher suite, ask for a client certificate, etc, or just to negotiate a new session key.